# Get Text from Div using jscript

Tags: javascript, html

How to get text from the div?

For example :

```
<script>
    function cahnge() {
        alert(document.getElementById('udin'));
   }

</script>
<div class="ayah">
<div class="udin" onclick="cahnge()" >udin</div>
</div>
```

I want to make alert message when the div get clicked and the message is the text of the div.

Thank you.

Comment: add `id='udin'` to div and use `document.getElementById('udin').innerHTML` to get text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    function change(aObject) {
        alert(aObject.textContent);
   }

</script>
<div class="ayah">
<div class="udin" onclick="change(this);">udin</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are close.

`getElementById` is checking that the div has an `ID`, but your div is a class.
You also need to add `.textContent` to get the actual content and not just the div object.

```
<script>
    function cahnge() {
        alert(document.getElementById('udin').textContent);
   }

</script>
<div class="ayah">
<div id="udin" onclick="cahnge()" >udin</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass this as an argument in onClick handler

```
<div class="ayah">
   <div class="udin" onclick="cahnge(this)" >udin</div>
</div>
```

In Javascript

```
function cahnge(obj) {
    alert(obj.innerText); 
    //alert(obj.innerHTML); 
}
```

In case if the div contains another elements then use 'innerHTML'. If not use 'innerText'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function change(aObject) {
        alert(aObject.innerHTML);
    }    
</script>

<div class="ayah">
<div class="udin" onclick="change(this);">udin</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getElementByClassName`:

```
<script>
    function cahnge() {
        alert(document.getElementsByClassName('udin')[0].innerHTML);
   }

</script>
<div class="ayah">
<div class="udin" onclick="cahnge()" >udin</div>
</div>
```

[Here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsoew34o/)

Comment: you have to use `document.getElementByClassName('udin')[0].innerHTML` in order to get the text.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you a have named the ***class*** udin and not the ***id***.
So make this change in the HTML code:

```
<div class="ayah">
<div id="udin" onclick="cahnge()" >udin</div>
</div>
```

In Javascript:

```
function cahnge() {
    alert(document.getElementById("udin").innerHTML);
```

}

InnerHTML helps you retrieve the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery, this is pretty easy to do using .text() - Use an ID on the element to target it specifically, you're using a class, which could have many like it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#target").click(function(){
    $("#target").text("Hello world!");
   });
});


 <div class="ayah">
 <div id="target" class="udin">udin</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="ayah">
    <div class="udin">udin</div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $elem = $('.udin');
      $elem.on('click', function() {
        var msg = $elem.html();
        alert(msg);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```